# Identifying AD Icon

Tags: active-directory

Can anyone tell me the meaning of the folder icon with the bronze/gold square in front of it?

[image: AD folder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This icon is to show that the folder is an Organizational Unit.

Please see the below link with a description of the difference between containers and OU's in Active Directory.

https://www.trivalentgroup.com/2015/11/active-directory-best-practice-ous-and-containers/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!